# Fixing common URL mistakes in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a Chrome extension that allows the user to enter a URL. Sometimes the user misses out the "http://". Without a complete URL Chrome seems to assumes the link is local file within the extension.

Currently my solution is this -

```
    var http_temp = $(this).attr("href");
    if($.trim(http_temp).substr(0, 4)!="http"){
        $(this).attr("href", "http://"+$(this).attr("href"));
    }
```

Is there a better way to deal with this? How would I detect the most common mistakes in URL's. Would regex or something else be better?

Thanks

Comment: Personally, I would first check that the given URL is not a valid URL using another scheme, e.g. ftp. Something like the regexp `^\w{2,8}:/` meaning any word of 2-8 characters followed by a colon and a slash or something similar.

Answer (score 0):

That sounds pretty good, albeit of course, no https, but I'm not sure how to resolve that either.

Perhaps, you could also check if the links exist with

```
function UrlExists(myUrl) {
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    http.open('HEAD', myUrl, false);
    http.send();
    return http.status != 404;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this, it should detect most protocols (not just http):

```
if( !(/^\w{3,5}\:\/\//i.test(url)) ) {
    url = 'http://'+url;
}
```

There are probably more sophisticated protocol detections, but this works for the most common ones.

Another option if you assume all users enter a http protocol: how about printing out the protocol before the input? That way the user knows that the protocol will be added. This is a common usability practice:

```
http://<input type="text">
```

Then, IF the users enter a protocol, it’s easily detected and stripped:

```
url = 'http://'+url.replace(/.*:\/\//,'');
```